# JS and CSS caching issue: possibly .htaccess related

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, htaccess

I've been using the HTML5 Boilerplate for some web projects for a while now and have noticed the following issue cropping up on some sites.

My CSS and JS files, when loaded by the browser, are being renamed to things like:

```
ce.52b8fd529e8142bdb6c4f9e7f55aaec0.modernizr-1,o7,omin,l.js
```

…in the case of `modernizr-1.7.min.js`

The pattern always seems to add `ce.` or `cc.` in front of the filename. I'm not sure what's causing this, and it's frustrating since when I make updates to those files, the same old cached file is being loaded. I have to explicitly call `modernizr-1.7.min.js?v=2` or something similar to get it to re-cache. I'd like to scrap it altogether but it still happens even when .htaccess is empty. Any ideas? Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

Comment: are you using the build script?

Comment: Is this all browsers, or one in particular?

Comment: Are you using any extensions that mess with JS or CSS files? I know some of the CSS Reload extensions will 'overwrite' previous versions of CSS files in-memory with renamed versions like this.

Answer (score 2):

Going by the [accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299115/why-is-my-wordpress-php-header-template-generating-oddly-coded-paths-and-transclu), do you have [`mod_pagespeed` enabled](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/module.html) on your server?